# laravel error: Trying to get property of non-object (\show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications

I'm making a discussion forum app with laravel and i face this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fourm\resources\views\discussion\show.blade.php) at
>   PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\fourm\storage\framework\views/a2f2c494b8859e0552bfa22c40ceb4065b2efbe5.php',
>   array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
>   'channels' => object(Collection), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag),
>   'd' => null, 'best_answer' => null))in CompilerEngine.php (line 59)

This is my controller code:

```
public function show($slug)
{
     $discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();
     $best_answer = Reply::where('best_answer', 1)->first();
     return view('discussion.show')->with('d', $discussion)->with('best_answer', $best_answer);
}
```

This is my view code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <img src="{{ $d->user->avatar }}" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span>{{ $d->user->name }}, <b>( {{ $d->user->points }} )</b></span>
            @if($d->is_being_watch_by_user())
                <a href="{{ route('discussion.unwatch', ['id' => $d->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">unwatch</a>
            @else
                <a href="{{ route('discussion.watch', ['id' => $d->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">watch</a>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <h4 class="text-center">
                <b>{{ $d->title }}</b>
            </h4>
            <hr>
            <p class="text-center">
                {{ $d->content }}
            </p>

            <hr>

            @if($best_answer)
                <div class="text-center" style="padding: 40px;">
                    <h3 class="text-center">BEST ANSWER</h3>
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <img src="{{ $best_answer->user->avatar }}" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span>{{ $best_answer->user->name }} <b>( {{ $best_answer->user->points }} )</b></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            {{ $best_answer->content }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
                    <span>
                        {{ $d->replies->count() }} Replies
                    </span>
            <a href="{{ route('channel', ['slug' => $d->channel->slug ]) }}" class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-xs">{{ $d->channel->title }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    @foreach($d->replies as $r)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <img src="{{ $r->user->avatar }}" alt="" width="40px" height="40px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span>{{ $r->user->name }} <b>( {{ $r->user->points }} )</b></span>
                @if(!$best_answer)
                    @if(Auth::id() == $d->user->id)
                        <a href="{{ route('discussion.best.answer', ['id' => $r->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Mark as best answer</a>
                    @endif
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <p class="text-center">
                    {{ $r->content }}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                @if($r->is_liked_by_user())
                    <a href="{{ route('reply.unlike', ['id' => $r->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Unlike <span class="badge">{{ $r->likes->count() }}</span></a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('reply.like', ['id' => $r->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Like <span class="badge">{{ $r->likes->count() }}</span></a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @if(Auth::check())
                <form action="{{ route('discussion.reply', ['id' => $d->id ]) }}" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reply">Leave a reply...</label>
                        <textarea name="reply" id="reply" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn pull-right">Leave a reply</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            @else

                <div class="text-center">
                    <h2>Sign in to leave a reply</h2>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: In your error, this shows you: `'d' => null, 'best_answer' => null`. Try to `dd($d);` and `dd($best_answer);`

Comment: both returning null

Comment: That's why you got the error! The record is not exists as per your query!

Comment: i didn't mentioned that i get this error when i make new post, i think best_answer and discussion are null by default

Comment: You just tried to get records by query and used them in your view. Simply, you will use null record and so that gave you error "Trying to get property of non object" You are accessing object with null values!

Comment: thank you hiren 

i have fixed it by adding this if statement

if (!$d) {
            $this->store();
            session()->flash('error', 'Discussion not found.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

Comment: Np, you're Welcome! I have posted my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access property with null objects, and that's why you got the error like "Trying to get property of null object".

As per our discussion in comments, you are getting `null` values in both queries and that's the reason for error!

Try to add `if..else` condition like below:

```
if (!$d) {   
     session()->flash('error', 'Discussion not found.'); 
     return redirect()->back(); 
} else {
    return view('discussion.show')->with('d', $discussion)->with('best_answer', $best_answer);
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because both queries return `null`:

```
$discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$best_answer = Reply::where('best_answer', 1)->first();
```

So, you need to check for empty result manually with `is_null()` or `empty()` or just:

```
if (!$discussion) {
    abort(404);
}
```

Or use `findOrFail()` to throw an exception if no record found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not returning an object and accessing it as an array. It can be a common error.

Answer (score -1):

I solved mine by adding: `<?php error_reporting(0);?>` on page where i got error. :D